# How to use AFNetworking to get S3 Bucket Location

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, afnetworking

I've managed to get AFAmazonS3Manager working for listing buckets, getObject, putObject, and deleteObject, but I can't seem to get it to work for getting a the region a bucket is in.

The code I'm using for the request is:

```
-(void)getBucketLocation:(NSString *)bucketName {

  AFAmazonS3Manager *s3Manager = [[AFAmazonS3Manager alloc] initWithAccessKeyID:self.accessKey secret:self.secretKey];
  [s3Manager.requestSerializer setBucket:bucketName];

  [s3Manager GET:@"/?location" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    //do something with successful response
  } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSString *xmlResponse = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:operation.responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Didn't get bucket location: %@", error);
  }];
}
```

The response always comes back with a 403-forbidden error, and the `xmlResponse` string includes `<Error><Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code><Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message>`

The access key and secret access key are the same that I use for list, put, delete, and get requests, and the IAM user has permissions for "s3:GetBucketLocation".

Switching over to the AWS iOS SDK is my last resort, but I'd rather stick with the relative simplicity of AFAmazonS3Manager if I can. Any pointers? Thanks!

Comment: Look more closely at `parameters`. What are those for? I'm speculating based on knowledge of the API and signature generation, but I suspect the correct "key" ("path") is probably just "/" and you may need to tell this library to append the `?location` query string via a different mechanism.  Doing this via `parameters` is a guess, as I am unfamiliar with this library itself.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Thanks for the suggestion. Amazon's [REST API documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketGETlocation.html) says getBucketLocation doesn't use parameters, so I just tried with an empty dictionary for the parameters, with the same result. Using just "/" for the key resulted in a ListBucket response.

Comment: That is only true if "parameters" means the same thing in both contexts.  I would call "location" a query string *parameter* but you may be right.  It seems entirely possible that the library you're using just failed to handle certain cases, such as this one.  That's a pretty common problem (and one of the big reasons I wrote all of my own libraries for S3 and many other AWS services from scratch).  Instead of an empty dictionary, what about "location" = (empty string) with path "/"?

Comment: Or perhaps setting the path to "?location" without the leading slash?  These are not exactly guesses, as I say, I'm thinking about how the API and signing algorithms work while flying blind about how the code might tinker with the components you supply and end up with the right result, accidentally or on purpose.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I'll give them a shot when I have some extra time this week. My guess is you're most likely right about the library failing to handle certain cases. The big question will be which of the three options will end up being the least frustrating in the long run: figuring out the solution with AFNetworking, writing my own library, or using Amazon's iOS SDK.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Yep, still no luck with AFNetworking. Just using "/" for the path, with several combinations of parameters involving "location" still return either a ListBucket or 403-Forbidden response. I'm curious about the libraries you wrote yourself-- have you tried GetBucketLocation with those, and is it successful?